# problem in obtaining result using java script map function

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
hi i am getting result from the database as below format and i am using javascript map function to customise my returned json result
```

and the problem here is i get the processed result twice if i declare the **mydata** object literals outside the map function,but if i declare the **mydata** object literals within the map i get expected output i don't know whats happening beyond the scene can please help me to solve my problem

```
what is the difference between two declaration could you  please explain me why this happening

data = [
    { "name" : "xyz", "date" : "28-09-2018"},
    { "name" : "abc","date" : "29-09-2018"}
]


let mydata = {}
let result =  data.map((item) => {
   mydata[item.date] = item
   return mydata
})
console.log(JSON.stringify(result,null,2))



declaring **mydata** outside map function i get this resutl:
[

  {
    "28-09-2018": {
      "name": "xyz",
      "date": "28-09-2018"
    },
    "29-09-2018": {
      "name": "abc",
      "date": "29-09-2018"
    }
  },
  {
    "28-09-2018": {
      "name": "xyz",
      "date": "28-09-2018"
    },
    "29-09-2018": {
      "name": "abc",
      "date": "29-09-2018"
    }
  }
]

declaring **mydata** within the map function i obtain below result
[

  {
    "28-09-2018": {
      "name": "xyz",
      "date": "28-09-2018"
    }
  },
  {
    "29-09-2018": {
      "name": "abc",
      "date": "29-09-2018"
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

The callback of `Array#map` returns an element of the new array. Take a look at the doc [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Syntax)

**Global declaration:**

`mydata` is declared gloabl and in the callback function of `map`, you are adding values to `mydata` object (`mydata[item.date] = item`) then returning the object reference. Now the point is, you are returning the same object reference for each item of the new array. Look closely, every item is **identical** in the final array (nested object). So, you are returning the same element for every iteration NOT distinct element.

**Local declaration**

When you declare the object inside the callback function, you are creating a distinct object for each iteration and every element of the new array will have a different object.

Hope this will help!